# Replace commas with underscores in concatenated control values

Tags: jquery

I want to concatenate the values of multiple controls with underscores. Here is my code so far:

```
var controls = $("[name='ctrl\\[\\]']").map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get();

alert(controls.split(',').join('_'));
```

Currently, it looks like the value of `controls` is, for example, `93(ok),n94(nok),91(3.52)`.

Comment: The code should work just fine. are you sure your not getting any errors in the console? Please include your html code, this will improve the change that you will receive an answer that solves your problem

Comment: If you change the last line to `alert(controls.join('_'))`—how does this differ from your desired output? Also, could you edit your post to include what you _expect_ the output to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks

You resolve my issue :)

Work's fine !  :)

```
controle = controle.join('_');
alert(controle);
```